# sh script cannot run process

Tags: debian, shell-script

I have fairly simple sh script that checks if process is running, if not then start it.
My problem is that sh script cant start the program for some reason...

Here's my script:

```
#!/bin/sh
if ps x |grep -v grep |grep -c CCcam >/dev/null
then
echo “cccam… ok”
else
echo “cccam… restarting”
/emu/cccam/CCcam.x86 &
fi
```

Now i run script manually to see if it works

```
root@lenovo:/emu/cccam# /emu/script/cccam_check.sh
▒cccam▒ restarting▒
```

It seems that script sees that cccam is not running, then tries to start it, but fails...

```
root@lenovo:/emu/cccam# ps x |grep -v grep |grep -c CCcam 
0
```

If i start proccess manually then it starts just fine

```
root@lenovo:/emu/cccam# ./CCcam.x86 &
[1] 32712
root@lenovo:/emu/cccam#
```

Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Do you get an error message when the script fails to start? that should indicate the issue.

Comment: I get no error whatsoever.

Comment: Does it work if you enter `bash /emu/script/cccam_check.sh` ?

Comment: BTW, you should replace the curly quotes and ellipsis characters with normal quotes and periods, to prevent those splotches.

Comment: When you start it manually, does it actually stay running in the background, or has it not in fact exited?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
#!/bin/sh
if ps x |grep -v grep |grep -c CCcam >/dev/null
then
   echo “cccam… ok”
else
   echo “cccam… restarting”
   cd /emu/cccam/
   restart="./CCcam.x86"
   $restart &
fi
```

Comment: Why would this be better than the OP's solution? fully qualifying like the OP did is better practice than "assuming" your cd worked. The only reason I see why this might work is if the CCcam app is depending on something else and uses relative paths.